# How does really c gives memory for int and long long?

Tags: c, memory, sizeof, memory-address

I know that in C type int is 4 bytes and long long is 8 bytes. However, as I checked, if you declare two int varuables consequently, (for example int a; int b;) the difference between their addresses is 8 and if you do the same for long long varuables, the difference will be 4.
There is my code:

```
void ckeck()
{
    int ai = 0;
    int bi = 0;
    printf("%llu\n",(unsigned long)(&bi - &ai));
    unsigned long long a = 3*INT_MAX;
    unsigned long long b = 0;
    printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)(&b-&a));
}
```

Comment: _"I know that in C type int is 4 byte"_ - No, you don't. Here are the fundamental types: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type - and here are shortcuts: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignof

Comment: *"... for long long variables, the difference will be 4."* Ok, but that isn't 4 bytes, that's 4 times the size of a `long long`.

Comment: Just because you declare two variables consecutively doesn't mean the compiler will put them into memory next to each other in the order that you expect. The compiler can put them anywhere it wants, in any order that it wants.

Comment: ... which is the answer to the question posed in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes.

First, the size of `int` is not standardised. For fixed types you would use `int32_t` from `stdint.h`. On some platforms it might be 64 bits and on others 16.

Second you are using pointer arithmetic to derive the size, which doens't work that way. You should use `sizeof(int)` for that.

consider this code:

```
int i[10];
int* iter = i;
while(iter != i+10)
{
  *iter = 123;
  iter+=1;
}
```

Here iter gets incremented by one every time so that it points to the next int. But since int (usually) isn't one byte big, your compiler will replace this with `iter += sizeof(*iter) * 1`, so that you make a step of exactly one int. This is because usually you don't want to point to the address halfway an int.